# How to scroll to specific position in BlackBerry web browser?

Tags: javascript, blackberry, scroll

How to scroll down / up to the specific position by using JavaScript in BlackBerry web browser?

Are properties like scrollOffset, scrollTop, scrollLeft etc. are supported? If not what code can be used?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you are writing the web app using HTML to display in the browser.

Create the location you would like to navigate to using the name attribute of the a tag.

```
<H2><A NAME="purchasing">Purchasing</A></H2>
```

Create a link that will navigate the user to that section of the page.

```
<A HREF="anameexample.html#purchasing">Purchasing</A>
```

You can place as many links and section as you need as long as the name attribute is different.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will work, but bear in mind that the name attribute of the <a> tag is now depreciated (http://derickrethans.nl/html-name-attribute-deprecated.html). It is better to use an id attribute on a div or heading to get the same effect.